# "zu verkaufen" signs

Tags: verb, preposition, usage

Isn't it supposed to be "zum Verkauf"? Any reason why a verb is used in these signs?

As I understand it - Ich habe ein Haus zu verkaufen - house *to* sell
Ich habe ein Haus zum Verkauf - house *for* sale.

"zum Verkaufen" with a large V (noun - das Verkaufen) is also an option? Or even "zu Verkaufen"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preference of verb constructions on German signs is not a matter of correctness, but of idiomacy and custom. They are contractions from statements such as:

> Ich habe ein Haus zu verkaufen.
>   
>   → Haus zu verkaufen!
>
> Ich habe ein Fahrrad zu verschenken.
>   
>   → Fahrrad zu verschenken!
>
> Ich habe ein Zimmer zu vermieten.
>   
>   → Zimmer zu vermieten!

Nominalizations such as

> Ich biete ein Haus zum Verkauf an.
>   
>   → Haus zum Verkauf!
>
> Ich biete ein Fahrrad zur Schenkung an.
>   
>   → Fahrrad zur Schenkung!
>
> Ich biete ein Zimmer zur Miete an.
>   
>   → Zimmer zur Miete!

are not wrong, but they are considered gobbledegook (Papierdeutsch).

Answer (score 6):

You are correct with your translations

> Haus zu verkaufen - house to sell
>
> Haus zum Verkauf - house for sale.

There are just different customs in English and German which version to use for sale signs.

It is very common to use *zu verkaufen*. Using *zum Verkauf* is used less frequently, and I would not expect *zum Verkaufen* at all.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich stimmt, ich hatte eher denTeil _zu verkaufen_ / _zum Verkauf_ im Blick. Ich hoffe, das ist jetzt klarer.

Comment: But Interestingly, signs "Zum Mitnehmen" are very common.

Comment: @Eller: Bei Häusern seltener. Aber wenn man Tomaten verkauft mit einem Schild "zum Verkaufen", dann erwartet man offenbar, dass die Kunden sie nicht verzehren, sondern ihrerseits verkaufen.

Answer (score 0):

The correct signage is

> zu verkaufen

That's short for

> Dieses Haus **ist zu verkaufen**.

which is a different way to write

> Ich muss dieses Haus verkaufen.

You may know this from English already:

*I must sell this house.*

*I **have to sell** this house.*

---

The alternative is

> Dieses Haus steht zum Verkauf.

Shortening this to *zum Verkauf* isn't common.

Comment: "Dieses Haus ist zu verkaufen" sagt mit nichten, dass **ich** es verkaufen **muss**. Wer es verkauft ist nicht gesagt. Ob es derjenie verkaufen muss oder will liegt im Dunkeln.